# Как сделать кнопку адаптивной?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Хотел выставить кнопку по центру,чтобы была адаптивна,нужно указать данные

```
setBounds(x,y,w,h);
```

Можете пожалуйста подсказать

Comment: Если возникнут вопросы - пишите их под ответом, чтобы мне пришли уведомления. Если все ок и ответ помог вам, то можете поставить галочку слева от ответа. См. справку [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А не вариант взять размеры экрана и плясать от них?
*(Я не сильный игродел, но не знаю как скоро тут специалист по LibGDX объявится.)*
**p.s.**
уже после написания ответа полистал по данной теме сообщения в https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ и они в целом поступают также (*считают все вручную*).

---

#### К делу

Для начала разберемся как в принципе работать с размерами предмета относительно экрана (*про центрирование произвольной кнопки тоже будет ниже*)

В данном случае для примера будет браться вот такая кнопка внизу экрана с равноудаленным отступом от краёв снизу, слева и справа.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Соответственно, нам нужно будет вычислить координаты и границы, зависимые от размеров экрана

```
// получаем ширину и высоту экрана
int screenWidth  = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
int screenHeight = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();

// отступ от краёв экрана
int padding = 50; 
// высоту кнопки мы устанавливаем самостоятельно
// хотя если сильно нужно можно и в процентном соотношении посчитать
int buttonHeight = 100;
// ширина кнопки равна ширине экрана с вычером двух отступов справа и слева
int buttonWidth  = screenWidth - padding * 2;

// вычитаем из высоты экрана высоту кнопки и отступ
// и получаем смещение по оси Y
int buttonY = screenHeight - buttonHeight - padding;
// смещение по оси x равно отступу от краёв экрана
int buttonX = padding;
```

Таким же способом можно высчитывать и более сложные вещи.
Например, если у нас две кнопки в ряду:

```
// вычитаем из ширины экрана отступы и делим на количество кнопок
int buttonWidth  = (screenWidth - padding * 3)/2;
```

или высчитывать в процентном соотношении от размеров экрана

```
// указываем наши проценты
int percent = 25;

// умножаем на количество процентов и делим на 100
//
//  на случай если не помним школу: 
//
//  buttonWidth        percent
// -------------   =  ---------
//  screenWidth          100
//
int buttonWidth  = screenWidth * percent / 100;
```

#### Выравнивание произвольной кнопки по центру

в таком случае нам нужно плясать от размеров кнопки и от размеров экрана

**Логика простая**:

1. из размера экрана вычитаем размер кнопки
   (*в результате получим свободное от кнопки пространство*)
2. и то что получилось делим на два
   *(так как свободного пространства по обе стороны от кнопки должно быть одинаковое количество)*
3. и получится координата по выбранной оси

```
int buttonY = (screenHeight - buttonHeight) / 2;
int buttonX = (screenWidth - buttonWidth) / 2;
```

и дальше можем устанавливать

```
setBounds(buttonX, buttonY, buttonWidth, buttonHeight);
```